# how to optimize an if condition for multiple values of same variable in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

How to write an `If Condition` having a single variable but multiple values.

Ex :
'Consider I have employee details filled in a data table

```
If (dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "548" Or dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "78787" Or dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "787" Or dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "11" Or dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "025" Or dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString() = "568") Then
MessageBox.Show("INSIDE")
End if
```

How can I optimize this If condition?

Comment: What type is _dt_?

Comment: `OrElse` will short circuit the `If`

Comment: What data type is the `Id` column? I would guess `Integer`. In that case, one thing you could do is treat the values as `Integers`. NEVER convert data that is not text to `Strings` unless you have to. In this case, `CInt(dt.Rows(0)("Id")) = 548` or `dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Integer)("Id") = 548` would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Select` statement with multiple items in one case:

```vb
Select dt.Rows(0).Items("Id").ToString()
Case "548", "78787", "787", "11", "025", "568"
    MessageBox.Show("INSIDE")
End Select
```